Tensor Operators and Spherical Harmonics
I've worked through a problem in Howard Georgi's Lie Algebras in Particle physics that states:
"The operator $(r_+)^2$ satisfies $[L^+, (r_+)^2] = 0$. It is therefore the $O_{+2}$ component of a spin 2 tensor operator. Construct the other components $O_m$. Note that the product of tensor operators transforms like the tensor product of their representations. What is the connection of this with the spherical harmonics $Y_{l,m}(\theta, \phi)$? Hint: let $ \ r_1 = \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), \ r_2 = \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \ \text{and} \ \ r_3 = \cos(\theta)$. Can you generalize this construction to to arbitrary $l$ and explain what's going on?"
I've found all the components of our spin 2 operator using the commutation relations of tensor operators with the SU(2) generators. I find that:
$$O_{+2} \ \propto \ (r_{+1})^2 \ , \ \ O_{+1} \ \propto \  r_{+1}r_0 + r_0 r_{+1} \ , \ \ O_{0} \ \propto \  (r_0)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(r_{+1}r_{-1} + r_{-1}r_{+1}) \ , \ \ \\
O_{-1} \ \propto \ r_0 r_{-1} + r_{-1} r_0 \ , \ \ O_{-2} \ \propto \ (r_{-1})^2 + 2(r_{-2}r_0 + r_0 r_{-2})
$$
Whether or not the constants I've worked out that come from the matrix elements of the spin matrices comes down to me checking I've done the algebra here correctly. My question is for the second part of the question. I can't exactly see how the spherical harmonics come into play in this specific problem here.
It's apparent here that for every product of the position tensor operators here, the $r_i$'s, within a spin 2 operator component, the $O_m$'s, that their subscripts must correspond to the spin level we're at. For every product that appears, their subscripts "add up" to the spin level we're at.
It seems like for the five $r_i$ operators, that they can be generalized to a five dimensional spherical basis, similar to
$$
r_{\pm} = \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x \pm i y), \ \ r_0 = z
$$
and these form a closed algebra with the spin matrices. Are the $r_i$ a basis for the spherical harmonics? I think this would imply that the $O_i$'s are spherical tensor operators yes? If this is the case, is it true that for $ \ l \in \text{ {-s, -s+1,...,s-1,s} } $ that $O_l$ is itself a spherical harmonic?
If the spherical harmonics are tensor operators, then how is it true that in quantum mechanics, they can be both an eigen basis for wave functions and also an operator?

The spherical harmonics can be considered as tensor operators acting by multiplication on other spherical harmonics because
$$
Y_{\ell_2}^{m_2}(\theta,\phi)Y_{\ell_1}^{m_1}(\theta,\phi)=
\sum_{\ell} C^{\ell m}_{\ell_1m_1;\ell_2m_2} Y^m_{\ell}(\theta,\phi)\times k
$$
where $k$ is a factor that plays the role of the reduced matrix element.  Indeed, you can check the composition law for spherical harmonics and verify that $k$ is independent of $m_1,m_2$ as reduced matrix elements should be; in fact, $k$ is proportional to $C^{\ell 0}_{\ell_1 0;\ell_2 0}$ multiplied by dimensionality factors and a $\sqrt{4\pi}$.

Does this mean that the $O_i$'s are linear combinations of tensor operators with the $r_i$'s as a basis for them? Does this mean that all spin tensor operators are linear combinations of spherical harmonics?

Sorry I don’t understand your question.  I suppose you can think of the Y$_\ell^m$’s as powers of the $r_i$’s but you certainly can’t view spin states as powers of $r_i$’s.  Moreover it’s pretty moot to think this way: what matters is how the set transforms, irrespective of how the operators are constructed.  It’s not as if the reduced matrix elements were necessarily powers of some “elementary” matrix elements, and you can have two tensors with the same $\ell$ with completely different RME.

thanks for your response. And right exactly. Thats what I'm confused about. I'm not entirely sure what the textbook problem I'm looking for is asking for. I can certainly put the spherical harmonics for $l=2$ in a spherical basis, choose that basis to be my $r_i$'s, but I'm not sure if that's what's meant by "see whats going on". Certainly the spherical harmonics and the operators I deal with in the problem have a relation with each other, but, as you said, tensor spin operators are certainly not intuitively linear combos of spin states.

(I don’t like Georgi as a textbook so) I can’t read Georgi’s mind as to what he means by “what’s going on” beyond the observation that you can start with the spherical harmonics and recover from them tensor operators constructed from the $r_i$’s.

haha okay thanks. I felt like I was going mad. just overthinking though. thanks mate

So the last question:
"then how is it true that in quantum mechanics, they can be both an eigen basis for wave functions and also an operator?"
so look at ordinary cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$. From that we can make wave functions, e.g.:
$$\psi_{0,0}(x, y, z) = f(r) $$
is an eigenstate of $L^2, L_z$ with $l=0, m=0$...trivial.
$$\psi_{1,0}(x, y, z) = f(r)z = f(r)r\cos\theta \propto f(r)Y_1^0(\theta, \phi) $$
is an eigenstate of $L^2, L_z$ with $l=1, m=0$
Meanwhile, if I turn on an electric field $\vec E = E\hat z$, now I have a dipole operator:
$$ O_{1, 0} \propto \hat z \propto Y_1^0 $$
so $z$ is a coordinate, and $\hat z$ is an operator that can link states, a la:
$$ M = \langle l, m|\hat z|l', m'\rangle $$
Meanwhile
$$Y_2^0\propto (3\hat z\hat z - \hat r \hat r) $$ is the standard quadrupole operator and so on.
If you look at the spherical harmonics in cartesian coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics) you'll see the pattern for generalized $l$.
Also, if you have a general rank-N cartesian tensor (I'll use $N=3$ as an example), with $N^3$ components looking like:
$$ \hat T_{xxy} = T_{ijk} \hat x \hat x \hat y $$
and so on, you put that into "natural" from by:

symmetrizing it:

$$ S_{ijk} = \frac 1 6\big(
T_{ijk} + T_{jki} + T_{kij} +
T_{kji} + T_{ikj} + T_{jik} 
\big) $$

Subtracting the trace:

$$ N_{ijk} = S_{ijk} - \frac 1 {10}
\big(
(\delta_{ij}+\delta_{ji})S_{llk}+
(\delta_{ik}+\delta_{ki})S_{lkl}+
(\delta_{jk}+\delta_{kj})S_{kll} 
\big)
$$
$N_{ijk}$ now has $2N+1$ degrees-of-freedom that are in a one-to-one correspondence with the $2N+1$ spherical harmonics $Y_N^m$.
For me, the epiphany in understanding tensors etc was dropping how we learned vectors. We learn vectors at $(\hat x, \hat y, \hat z)$ being the basis of 3D space and they are represented by arrows with a magnitude and direction--we all heard that.
The problem is there is no way to generalize that. (I believe this is the adjoint representation of $SO(3)$).
In the spherical basis: $(r_-, r_0, r_+)$ (which I think is the fundamental representation of $SO(3)$, the significance of the $r_m$ is they are not arrows; rather, they are the geometric objects that are the 3 eigenvectors of $z$-rotations, with eigenvalue:
$$ \lambda_m(\theta) = e^{im\theta} $$
and they are closed under general rotations: changing the $z$ axis to the $z'$ axis just mixes the 3 vectors (or eigenstates if it's coordinate $(x, y, z)$).
Now, when you take dyadic products (or $n$-polyadic products), and do the proper linear combinations (with the help Clebsch-Gordon), you get a set of $2n+1$ operators that are closed under rotations, or if you're talking about wave functions, you get the $2n+1$ $Y_n^m$ spherical harmonics, which are ofc closed under rotations.
So to summarize: the $2l+1$ $Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$ are the closed (under general rotations) set of shapes that are eigenstates of $z$-rotations...that is, they form an irreducible representation $SO(3)$. When you promote the coordinates to operators, they're the spherical tensor operators.
One concern maybe that $3^N > 2N+1$ for $N>1$...there's a group theoretic way to handle this (Schur-Weyl duality and the Robison-Schensted correspondence) where you get things like:
$$ 3 \otimes 3 = 5 \oplus 3 \oplus 1 $$
which means if you combine 2 vector operators (dimension 3), you get a pure range 2 tensor operator (dimension 5), their cross-product (dimension 3...rotates like a vector), their dot product (dimension 1, is a scalar).
The relation to spin is, if you look at the combination of two vector spins:

you get the exact same breakdown.
At rank-3 you get:
$$ 3 \otimes 3 \otimes 3 = 7 \oplus 5 \oplus 3 \oplus 5 \oplus 3 \oplus 1 $$
and if you combine 3 vector bosons, you'll get states of total angular momentum with the same structure.
Finally, when it comes to fermions and spinors--of course there is no $(x, y, z)$ representation, and you see these description with flags and complex phases and so on...they're just "the things" that are eigenstates of $z$-rotations with with:
$$\lambda_{\pm \frac 1 2}e^{\pm i\theta} $$
no need to visualize them--just accept their existence as the fundamental representation of $SU(2)$.
